# Fix this grid using CSS Floats (or another method)

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this grid layout using floats (or another method):
[image]

But I cannot get to move grid number 8 (numbering in natural order left to right top to down) to occupy its position in left.
HTML:

```
<div class="blockContainer">

                    <ul id="RnP" class=" rnp">
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                        <li id="bigbox">6</li>
                        <li >7</li>
                        <li >8</li>
                        <li>9</li>
                        <li>10</li>
                        <li>11</li>
                        <li>12</li>
                        <li>13</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.blockContainer{
    position: absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:20%;
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 37em;
}
.rnp li{
    background: blue;
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    color: yellow;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#bigbox{
    width: 17em;
    height: 17em;   
}
.rnp{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

JS FIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/ebbj2sch/

Comment: Not possible using `float`due to the way it functions AFAIK.

Comment: Okay, is it possible if I don't use floats? inline-blocks?

Comment: You could probably hack something together but I think your best option would be something like [**masonry.js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Is this thing static?

Comment: What about using css? as in `display: table-row` `display: table-cell` and so on?

Comment: What are the constraint? the DOM can change? the layout is static (same number of boxes, the center is always 6?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with the markup you are using. Maybe with `flexbox` but an easier way would be to wrap the boxes next to the big one in an extra element.

```
<div class="blockContainer">
    <div id="RnP" class=" rnp">
        <div class="box">1</div>
        <div class="box">2</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
        <div class="box">4</div>
        <div>
            <div class="box">5</div>
            <div class="box">6</div>
        </div>
        <div id="bigbox">7</div>
        <div>
            <div class="box">8</div>
            <div class="box">9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">10</div>
        <div class="box">11</div>
        <div class="box">12</div>
        <div class="box">13</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And change the CSS to something like:

```
.blockContainer{
    position: absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:20%;
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 37em;
}
.rnp .box{
    background: blue;
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    color: yellow;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.rnp > div{
    float: left;
}

#bigbox{
    width: 17em;
    height: 17em;   
}
.rnp{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working solution in this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/fx3ygv2x/)

this is not the optimal solution, but it may work for you.
I'm assuming that your layout is fixed (the number of boxes, the order and etc').

also: in your fiddle, you used `em` for units, so i'll do the same.
(that's the reason I had to remove white spaces between the `<li>` in the HTML.)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li id="Big">6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 37em;
}
ul
{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    background: blue;
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
#Big
{
    width: 17em;
    height: 17em;
}
#Big + li + li
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 18em;
    left: 0;
}
#Big + li + li + li
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 18em;
    left: 27em;
}
```